# regexp using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has 3 items:

1. bet
2. betatter
3. betttt

I want to fetch those items from this table where t is repeated 3 or more times. I am using the below regxp query

```
select title
from table
where title regexp 't{3,}';
```

I am not getting the desired results, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost looks like a typo on your part, but if you want to search for `t` occurring three or more times in succession then the pattern you want is:

```
t{3,}
```

So you would want this query:

```
SELECT title
FROM table
WHERE title REGEXP 't{3,}';
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you want to search for three `t` anywhere in the title, then use the pattern `'t.*t.*t'`:

```
SELECT title
FROM yourTable
WHERE title REGEXP 't.*t.*t';
```

Comment: what if the t's are not in succession?

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer per your new requirements.  Please avoid changing your question after answers have already been given.